Linovo Thinkap T570 Screen Replacement options/starting point
I want to replace the display of my Lenovo ThinkPad T570. Where can I go to look at my options? I've seen some discussion involving needing to replace the display cable with a 40pin connector for some displays, but not why. Any advice on where I can learn more about this, or specific model recommendations would be appreciated.

To clarify: you're trying to upgrade your T570 from the 1080p panel (either touch or non-touch) to the 2160p panel?
